# The order of pole of $\frac{1}{(2\cos z -2 +z^2)^2} $at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the order of the pole of :

$$\frac{1}{(2\cos z -2 +z^2)^2}$$
at $z=0$

This is what I did :

$$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2} $$
then :

$$ \implies \frac{1}{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz}+z^2-2)^2} $$

How do I continue?

Comment: You can find the Maclaurin series representation for your function to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$
\cos z = 1 - \frac12 z^2 + \frac1{4!}z^4 + \cdots
$$
we have
$$
(2\cos z - 2 + z^2)^2 = (\frac1{12}z^4 + \cdots)^2 = \frac{1}{144}z^8 + \cdots
$$
where $\cdots$ denote higher order terms. This shows that your function has an $8$-fold zero in the denominator, so the order of the pole is $8$.

Comment: Why did you stop at $z^{4}$ ? if you continue lets say to $z^{8}$ you will have an order of 16.
what am I missing?

Comment: You only have to keep track of the first non-vanishing term. Taking additional terms just gives you:
$$(2\cos z + 2 + z^2)^2 = \frac{1}{144}z^8 - \frac{1}{2160} z^{12} + \cdots = z^8( \frac{1}{144} - \frac{1}{2160}z^4 + \cdots )$$
and we still have an $8$-fold zero. Only the $0$:th and $2$:nd order terms in the expansion of $\cos z$ will cancel.

Comment: Right! now it's all clear to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Near $z=0$:

$$2 (1-\cos{z}) = z^2 - \frac1{12} z^4 + \cdots$$

so that

$$z^2 -2 (1-\cos{z}) =   \frac1{12} z^4 + \cdots$$

Thus, the term in the denominator is $O(z^4)^2$ as $z \to 0$ and the pole is of order $8$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Let , $f(z)=2\cos z-2+z^2$. Find the order of zero of $f$.

$f'(z)=-2\sin z+2z$.

$f''(z)=-2\cos z+2$

$f'''(z)=2\sin z$

$f^{iv}(z)=2\cos z$.

Clearly , $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0$ , but $f^{iv}(z)\not= 0$. So $f$ has a zero of order $4$.

> So , $(2\cos z-2+z^2)^2$ has a zero of order $8$ at $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the polus $z=0$ is $8$. You can see this computing the derivates of $g(z)=(2\cos z-2+z^2)^2$ . The first darivate non zero in the origin is $g^{(8)}(z)$.

[image]

Comment: Do you **really** want to differentiate eight times by hand?

Comment: Wolfram differetiate for me! :)